# How can I add another organization and user to this organization?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am trying to setup my own ca-server and client.
After initializing ca-server with admin, I enrolled it with ca-client enroll cli commands.
Then I wanted to add another organization to the system.
I change the fabric-ca-server-config.yml files affiliations part then restart the server, then try to register and enroll new user to this organization with ca-client. But it failed with affiliation not found error. So i wonder this question.
After initilazing server with admin user,should every other user and organization precesses made from client cli?

What is for affiliation part in the faric-ca-server.yaml file?

How can I add another organization and user to this organization?

Answer (score 1):

Your question has three parts, I'll try to answer them one by one along with references for each.

**1. To add a new organization**

For adding a new organization, you'll first need to generate crypto materials for that organization, update the network config files and then submit a configuration update transaction to the channel. This will help you add a new organization to the existing channel. With this config update, the MSPs of the existing entities are updated. References: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/channel_update_tutorial.html

**2. To add a new user**

Assuming you have an admin identity that is "enrolled", you can use this identity to first register a new user and then enroll this registered user with the CA server and obtain the user identity. References: https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/users-guide.html

**3. Issuing requests**

You don't necessarily have to issue all the requests from the client-cli. Hyperledger Fabric has SDKs for the same. References: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/getting_started.html#hyperledger-fabric-sdks